# Find the minimum value in a column that is common to a grouping in another column

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

Suppose I have a simple dataframe like this one:

```
mydata <- data.frame(Name = c(rep("A",4),rep("B",3),rep("C",2),rep("D",2),"E"),
           Value = c(5,2,3,6,1,3,8,13,3,5,3,3)
```

I want to find which is the minimum `Value` that is shared by all `Name` (in this example, 3). So far I've created a column with the minimum `Value` for each `Name` with:

```
mydata$min <- ave(mydata$Value, mydata$Name, FUN = min)
```

but it's not the result I am looking for. I think I can group the `Name` with a combination of `unique()` and `mutate()` (from `dplyr`) but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We `split` the 'Value' by the 'Name' get the `intersect` using `Reduce` and apply `min` on it

```
mydata$min <- min(Reduce(intersect, split(mydata$Value, mydata$Name)))
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>%
  group_by(Value) %>% 
  mutate(flag = n_distinct(Name) == n_distinct(mydata$Name)) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(Min = min(Value[flag]), flag = NULL)
```

Comment: This works great on the example database but not on my real data, as I get a warning of `no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf` with both approaches. The real dataset has also negative values in `Value` and 0s (but this shouldn't hamper the methods you suggested), it doesn't have NAs, and all are integers. No NAs are present in `Name` as well, it's a vector of characters.

Comment: @LisaTedeschi It is possible that your original data may not have intersecting elements for all the 'Name'

Comment: That was the case, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the result by first building each group's vector of doubles, then finding the intersect of the vectors, and finally extracting the minimum value.

Using the tidyverse you can do so with:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

mydata <- data.frame(
  Name = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 3), rep("C", 2), rep("D", 2), "E"),
  Value = c(5, 2, 3, 6, 1, 3, 8, 13, 3, 5, 3, 3)
)

mydata %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarize(Values = list(Value)) %>%
  pull(Values) %>%
  reduce(intersect) %>%
  min()
```

Comment: This works great on the example database but not on my real data, as I get a warning of `no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf`. The real dataset has also negative values in `Value` and 0s (but this shouldn't hamper the methods you suggested), it doesn't have NAs, and all are integers. No NAs are present in `Name` as well, it's a vector of characters.

Comment: @LisaTedeschi This is most possibly because there's no single value that is present in all groups. You can verify if this is the case by skipping the last call to `min`.

Comment: That was the case, thanks.